# keep selected dynamic dropdown list after submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Below is my code to populate a dynamic list.

```
<?php
if(isSet($_POST['supplier'])) {

include 'db.php';

$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT SupplierBrand FROM plastic WHERE HeadingNo='".$_POST['supplier']."' ORDER BY SupplierBrand");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($supplierBrand);
?>
<option value="All" width="100px">--ALL--</option>
<?php
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) : ?>

<option value="<?php echo $supplierBrand; if($_POST['county'] == $supplierBrand) {echo "selected";} ?>" width="100px"><?php echo $supplierBrand; ?></option>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I added the code 
`if($_POST['county'] == $supplierBrand) {echo "selected";}` 
to try and retain my selected value onSubmit. This code in this context does not work. After debugging I noticed that the county value is undefined. 
This is error from chrome debugging:

```
Notice&lt;/b&gt;:  Undefined index: county
```

How to get the value county for which its on another page and further more the above php script value `$_POST['supplier']` is passed by use of jquery.

Below is the html code:

```
<div id="county_drop_down">
                        <select id="county" name="county" >
                            <option value="" width="100px">Supplier...</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                            <span id="loading_county_drop_down">
                            <img src="css/loader.gif" width="16" height="16" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Loading...</span>
                            <div id="no_county_drop_down">No lens type/design has been selected.</div>
```

For the javascript, please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056702/how-to-debug-using-firebug-and-show-the-value-of-radio-button/16057150?noredirect=1#16057150)

Comment: It's probably expecting an index (a number) instead of the String 'county'.

Comment: Change this isSet($_POST['supplier']) into isset($_POST['supplier']) in your code.

Comment: Please post the reveant HTML output of the rendered dropdown (not the source code). That would help in seeing what value you need to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loads of issues in your code here's a few of them to fix first.

`value="<?php echo $supplierBrand; if($_POST['county'] == $supplierBrand) {echo "selected";} ?>"`

will result in `value="(int) selected"` which is invalid HTML it should be this `value="<?php echo $supplierBrand;?>" <?php echo ($_POST['county'] == $supplierBrand) ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "" ; ?>`
Remember valid html is selected="selected" and checked="checked" etc.

You're missing your select open in your code above I assume its created else where?

Your country value is being posted in from another page so you need to st ore it locally and pass it back through this page when it reposts to its self.
I usually use hidden fields so if $_POST['country'] is incoming from another page on this page I would use `<input type="hidden" name="country" id="country" value="<?php echo $_POST['country'];?>" />`  This will make sure it received country from the previous page and always repopulates this field with whatever was inbound previous on the repost.

Then your if statement above will work fine as the $_POST['country'] will exist.

Finally as already pointed out isSet() should be all lower case isset()

Are you using a custom db class too ? it looks like mysqli or pdo but the prepare lists looks wrong should it not be `$mysqli->prepare()`?  Since you're using a prepare too you should be doing param binding rather than injecting $_POST['supplier'] into the prepare as at the moment your way of doing it makes the prepare kinda pointless and also makes you vulnerable to sql injection etc.