# On submit values lost

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a javascript that fires on change of radio button. On my radio button also have this code below.

```
<input type="radio"  name="design" style="vertical-align: middle"  value="1"   onchange="this.form.submit()"  <?php if(isset($_POST['design'])){ if($_POST['design'] == 1) {echo "checked";}} ?>/>
```

So when this group 'design' radio buttons changes this age is submit and data is loaded depending on which radio button.

I also have a javascript with code below.

```
$("#lensType input:radio[name='design']:checked").change(populate);
```

It fires though when a change occurs but now when the form is submit and it is loaded that execution of change is lost.  How can I retain that value or have this function execute still.

This function loads a combo dynamic select list depending on which radio button is selected.
At the same time the radio buttons load data on a table depending on what design it is.

Comment: If you'd like to execute the jQuery function, you probably should'nt submit the form and reload the page ?

Comment: True, the reason I do that is to load data as user filters but use of radio buttons and at the same depending on their previous choice load the relevant select list. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056702/how-to-debug-using-firebug-and-show-the-value-of-radio-button/16057150?noredirect=1#16057150 link as well for the whole javascript code.

Comment: Store the value in Hidden field before Submit and retrive it after submit